# Sub-string Extractor with Specific Keywords

Tags: code-golf, string

**Challenge**

The goal of this challenge is to make a function that takes an input string, a start keyword and a end keyword. The output extracted result is from (but excluded) the given start keyword to (but excluded) end keyword. The output sub-string follows the rules as below.

- In all cases, the leading/trailing spaces in output sub-string should be removed.
- If the given start keyword is an empty string, it means that the anchor is at the start of the input string. Otherwise, the first occurrence of the given start keyword is an start anchor. If there is no any occurrence of the given start keyword, the output is an empty string.
- If the given end keyword is an empty string, it means that the anchor is at the end of the input string. Otherwise, the first occurrence of the given end keyword is an end anchor. If there is no any occurrence of the given end keyword, the output is an empty string.
- If the location of start anchor is after than the location of end anchor, or a part of the first occurrence of the given start keyword and a part of the first occurrence of the given end keyword are overlapped, the output is an empty string.

Similar but different from [Extract a string from a given string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/50379/100303), the given start and end anchors are multiple characters.

Here's an ungolfed reference implementation in C#

```
private static string GetTargetString(string stringInput, string startKeywordInput, string endKeywordInput)
{
    int startIndex;
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(startKeywordInput))
    {
        startIndex = 0;
    }
    else 
    {
        if (stringInput.IndexOf(startKeywordInput) >= 0)
        {
            startIndex = stringInput.IndexOf(startKeywordInput) + startKeywordInput.Length;
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
        
    }

    int endIndex;
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(endKeywordInput))
    {
        endIndex = stringInput.Length;
    }
    else
    {
        if (stringInput.IndexOf(endKeywordInput) > startIndex)
        {
            endIndex = stringInput.IndexOf(endKeywordInput);
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
    
    
    //    Check startIndex and endIndex
    if (startIndex < 0 || endIndex < 0 || startIndex >= endIndex)
    {
        return "";
    }

    if (endIndex.Equals(0).Equals(true))
    {
        endIndex = stringInput.Length;
    }
    int TargetStringLength = endIndex - startIndex;
    return stringInput.Substring(startIndex, TargetStringLength).Trim();
}
```

**Example Input and Output**

The example input and output is listed as below.

| Input String | Start Keyword | End Keyword | Output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "C# was developed around 2000 by Microsoft as part of its .NET initiative" | ""(empty string) | ""(empty string) | "C# was developed around 2000 by Microsoft as part of its .NET initiative" |
| "C# was developed around 2000 by Microsoft as part of its .NET initiative" | ""(empty string) | ".NET" | "C# was developed around 2000 by Microsoft as part of its" |
| "C# was developed around 2000 by Microsoft as part of its .NET initiative" | "C#" | ""(empty string) | "was developed around 2000 by Microsoft as part of its .NET initiative" |
| "C# was developed around 2000 by Microsoft as part of its .NET initiative" | "C#" | ".NET" | "was developed around 2000 by Microsoft as part of its" |
| "C# was developed around 2000 by Microsoft as part of its .NET initiative" | ".NET" | ""(empty string) | "initiative" |
| "C# was developed around 2000 by Microsoft as part of its .NET initiative" | ""(empty string) | "C#" | ""(empty string) |
| "C# was developed around 2000 by Microsoft as part of its .NET initiative" | ".NET" | "C#" | ""(empty string) |
| "C# was developed around 2000 by Microsoft as part of its .NET initiative" | "ABC" | "C#" | ""(empty string) |
| "C# was developed around 2000 by Microsoft as part of its .NET initiative" | ".NET" | "XYZ" | ""(empty string) |
| "C# was developed around 2000 by Microsoft as part of its .NET initiative" | "ABC" | "XYZ" | ""(empty string) |

**Rules**

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). The answer with the fewest bytes wins.

Comment: Why does the empty string match the start and end of a string? Doesn't it match all the gaps in a string?

Comment: The rule is, if the keyword is an empty string, it means that the anchor is at the start or the end.

Comment: You may want to add that to your question.

Comment: @Razetime Thank you for the suggestion. Already updated.

Comment: Can the output have leading/trailing spaces?

Comment: The leading/trailing spaces should be removed, please check the example input and output.

Comment: If "as" and "" are given as start and end keywords, should the output be "developed around 2000 by Microsoft as part of its .NET initiative" (everything after "was", which contains "as") or "part of its .NET initiative" (everything after the exact word "as")?

Comment: Also, what should we do if the given keyword appears multiple times in the string? If the string is "abc 1 def 2 abc 3 def", delimiting from "abc" to "def" may result in "1", "3", or "1 def 2 abc 3".

Comment: @Bubbler from his code, it seems like it will be the first one, i.e., "developed...", but a clarification by OP is required..

Comment: The output should be "developed around 2000 by Microsoft as part of its .NET initiative" (everything after "was", which contains "as"). The first occurrence of the given keyword is an anchor.

Comment: Suggested test case: `"", ".NE?T"`, which should return an empty string but will fail if unescaped regular expressions are used.

Comment: Please make sure the challenge is specified fully in the text, so that readers don't need to [study the test cases to figure out what's intended](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8078/20260).

Comment: @JimmyHu You didn't answer my second comment. Does the "first occurrence" rule apply to both start and end keywords? Should "abc 1 def 2 abc 3 def", "abc", "def" give "1" then?

Comment: @Bubbler Already updated. If there is any problem about details or clarity still existed in the description of this question, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Suggested testcase: start keyword `"Not in string"`, end keyword: `""`.

Comment: If "wa" and "as" are given as keywords, is the correct output the empty string?

Comment: @Neil Thank you for mentioning that specific situation. The answer is yes and the description has been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 24 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319) ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

Full program that prompts for array of `[EndKeyword,StartKeyword,InputString]`. Requires 0-based indexing.

```apl
⌂deb⊃(⌽⊢↓⍨1⍳⍨⊣,⍷)/⌽¨@0⊢⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qG@qp/@jtgkGXI862gv@P@ppSklNetTVrPGoZ@@jrkWP2iY/6l1h@Kh3M5B61LVY51Hvdk19oNyhFQ4GIPm@qf@BGv8rgEEBl7q6Agg5KyuUJxYrpKSWpebkF6SmKCQW5ZfmpSgYGRgYKCRVKvhmJhflF@enlSgAVRUkFpUo5KcpZJYUK@j5uYYoZOZllmQmlmSWpapzwQ0GydDMcLCpNHU3rYwHmgq3geqGgx1NQ6Np7HJHJ2famB4RGUVT10PMp7LzAQ)

`⎕` prompt for input

`⊢` on that…

`⌽¨@0` reverse all the elements that occur at offset 0

`(`…`)/` reduce from the right using the following tacit function:

`⍷` indicate with a Boolean list all the places where the left argument begins in the right argument

`⊣,` prepend the left argument to that

`1⍳⍨` find the offset of the first 1

`⊢↓⍨` drop that many leading elements from the right argument

`⌽` reverse (next time around, do this from the end, and after that, revert order)

`⊃` disclose the enclosure caused by the reduction from a 1-dimensional array to a 0-dimensional array

`⌂deb` **d**elete **e**nding (leading and trailing) **b**lanks

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>80</s>  75 bytes

This contains some unprintable characters which are escaped below.

```javascript
(s,a,b)=>s.replace(b||/$/,"").replace(a,"").match(/ *(.*?) *|$/)[1]||""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZHLTsMwEEWldtevGE27sKMQB/YBQcQSVix4iMUkccAoxJFtUiHl30NCo7aIPhBQS17YujrHd/xCNdnUqModlTqTbR61zPrkJzw6tYGRVUGpZEnTiJnwcYx8eUc@jrrjK7n0mYkReCzwzjh442Ym@MPxY9MgttYZiADjKczJQiZrWehKZkBGv5UZnIRhCMk7XKnUaKtzB12qIuNA56CcheD68gZUqZwip2qJk0mqS6sLGRT6ieWs4/uA2G/OYVhC/Kdxm7APDtK/CDcL4umXTr3ggHUWtmWhX9s20z@5qzY9/Sfz7R61Xn83ewhvD55fxOvQ/cTbu/s@upc45HYEyX77ywP945xw4VtNGtsP)

#### Commented

```javascript
(s, a, b) =>          // s = input string, a = start keyword, b = end keyword
  s.replace(          // replace in s:
    b || /$/,         //   look for the end keyword, or the regex /$/ if it's empty
    "\3"              //   and replace it with ETX (end of text)
  )                   //
  .replace(           // replace in the resulting string:
    a,                //   look for the start keyword
    "\2"              //   and replace it with STX (start of text)
  )                   //
  .match(             // attempt to match:
    /\2 *(.*?) *\3|$/ //   "\2"    STX
  )                   //   " *"    followed by optional whitespace
                      //   "(.*?)" followed by a non-greedy string (the payload)
                      //   " *"    followed by optional whitespace
                      //   "\3"    followed by ETX
                      //   "|$"    OR match an empty string to make sure that
                      //           match() doesn't return null
  [1] || ""           // return the payload string, or an empty string if undefined
```

Comment: You need to switch your `replace` calls in case the keywords overlap, e.g. keywords `wa` and `as` should fail on the example string.

Comment: @Neil Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>86</s> <s>77</s></sup> 75 bytes

Saved 9 bytes thanks to [movatica](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/86751/movatica)!!!
Saved 2 bytes thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)!!!

```python
lambda s,a,b:s[s.find(a):(b in s)*s.find(b)if b else None][len(a):].strip()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVLRTsIwFH3fV9yMh62mEkQTE5KZKPFRnnxQgZh2u5XGuS5tQZHw7bMdTCYhPihL2p7dtufce3vKpZ2p4rwSyaTK2RvPGBjKKB@YsekKWWQxI4OYgyzAkJNtiBMpgAPmBmGkCpyOcyz8wWnXWC3LmFQWjTXPQmpjIYE4HClbc7jt4iWkEDZj2NnN3dHtfRNv8PXN8MBvhgvMVYlZSIKNlMFUFVmttU@xj9uSm/nh8am1lExbx4sfJaYWd5zDDrwzA9/awLSaO81@r9cDvoQ7mWpllLDgTnkSUAKkNeDFXfXSSmblAv/D5e8eLYk/Z/CT5tD4hcy1Np1h@oradzaazPuXF2lEoUZn5xEJjNs4XrcDoTQ4S1P0Dvx09myZk0LbPhSaRyeDANznUxSxoe4@cFKHSudgG4soXJm1r3TFNgtfh3B65YB2YLWtcKyTBKfriFRf)

Comment: Because `str.find()` returns -1 if not found and `str[-1:x]==''` for all x, you can skip the `(a in s)*` check for another 11 bytes. Nice work!

Comment: @movatica But I add `len(a)` to the `s.find(a)` so it's not `-1` if `a` isn't in `s` but `len(a)-1`, thanks anyway! :)

Comment: Look at your code again: You're using `(a in s)*(b...)` and that is not necessary, see your tests. Nothing to do with `len(a)` Maybe there are cases, where it would fail.

Comment: @movatica No, because the `a in s` will make it `s[len(a)-1:0]` so an empty string will be returned.

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVLfT8IwEH7fX3EZD1u1EgQTE5KZKPFRn3xQgZh2u4bGuS69giLhb58dY4roE6HJ/ei19931@pVLNzPFoFLJpMrFm8wEEBdcDmlMXaWLLBbsNMfCm2EsQRdA7GR7IplWIAFzQqivEJt2yVldxqxySI5elLbkIIE4DDlsZNT50d3724c23vrXN6P9LQsaMMLUFNk32n/Z@xUa/fj03BoW4EeJqcMGZ9SBd0GQ4QJzU/qgsGbua/R7vR7IJdzp1BoyyoG/VQrrwCjQjqAu6IehnRZOL7CpdRhWnXu0Jg7u4DfMH2FBOsP0FW09tmgy719epBGHjXc@iFhA/uB44wyUseBZyLFm3Kdn1A6fOOzygUP7o2wYgF91iyom7vNBsk2otLpwsYrCFa3r56xEY@Q6hLMr71jvrLYvHNskwek6YtUX "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @movatica Added proper testcase for this, your change fails.

Comment: Ah, yes, I get your point. It fails for e.g. `a='X', b='part'`.

Comment: [77 bytes](https://tio.run/##rVJRT8IwEH7fr7iMh62mEkQTE5KZKPFRnnxQgZh2a6VxrkuvoEj47bMdTCYhPihN2rte2@@7u37l0s50cV7JZFLl7I1nDJAyygc4xq5URRYzMog5qAKQnGxDnCgJHESOAnJRxEimY2/d1WkXrVFlTCor0OKzVAYtJBCHI21rFHdcvIQUwmYOO7u1O7q9b@KNf30zPLDNxELkuhRZSIINFYpUF1nNtQ@x77cpN@vD41PLlMxYhys@SpFascMcduCdIXxzAzN67jj7vV4P@BLuVGo0amnB3fIgoCUoi@DJXfXKKmbVQvwHy789WhJ/zuAnzKH5C5hrbToT6aswvrPRZN6/vEgjCrV3dh6RAN3B8bodSG3AiZoKr8BPJ8@WOCm05UOh@XQyCMANn6KMkbr3wEkdKp2CbSyjcIVrX@mKbQxfh3B65RzjnNW2wrFJEjFdR6T6Ag "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @movatica Ah, now that's a good one - thanks! :D

Comment: [74 bytes](https://tio.run/##rVJRT8IwEH7fr7iUh62mEgQTE5KRKPFRnnxQx2LarZVGXJe2oEj47bMdTCYhPihN2l57ve@7u37lys5UMahEPK3m9I3lFAyhhA1NYrpCFnlE8TCZqIKTiIEswOCznYPhNGEjhNI0mfPCv0u7xmpZRriy3FjzLKQ2FmKI0ETZOti5ixdEADVz3Nmv3cntfXPf2Nc34yPHnC/5XJU8RzjYUhmeqSKvuQ4hDu025XZ9eHxqbSXV1uHyj5Jnlu8xxx14pwa@uYFqtXCc/V6vB2wFdzLTyihhwb3yIKAESGvAk7vqpZXUyiX/D5aPPVkSf87gJ8yx@QuYa20249kr176z4XTRv7rMQgK1dTEIcWCc43TdDoTS4BRNuFfgp5NnS5wE2vIh0Hw6Hgbghk9RRIa4eGC4viqdgm0kQrQ2G1/pmm43tkFwPnKGdsZ6V2Gi45inmxBXXw) by using `None` instead of `len(s)`.

Comment: @movatica Magical - thanks! :D

Comment: Actually, the last one wasn't me ;) Nice catch ovs, totally forgot about boolean indexing!

Comment: @ovs Oops, sorry it's was *you* who performed the magic - thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 66 bytes

```ruby
->w,s,e,r=Regexp{"#{w[/#{r.quote s}\K.+(?=#{r.quote e})/]}".strip}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZBND8FAEIbvfsVkeyGqGvfV0DgJB3HweSidlU3Ert2tkqa/vb4VQSQc5jLPzPvOOyqa7TJGs0o9trWNtqI9XOBWJsRK4nHVSpSzjoRB0Omk7ZSLHs1bmJaq05Q42igu00wDBeJbEAcaQtzgUkgMIVAiWoVQc10XZjvo8LkSWjADhykZKAOCATcanG6rD3zFDQ8M3yApFGR0aLOxBpuQU02B/tXhyeDIfzV5JerdVB@ob92n@n@ks/59qN8TndXyqz9882j/IvVV4Q1uNP0vlgfD0aftd5gJcTr@grI9)

Another method without the use of regex,

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 72 bytes

```ruby
->w,s,e{"#{w[((w+s).index(s)+s.size rescue 0)...w.rindex(e)||0]}".strip}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZA9b8IwEIZ3fsXJWRKRWhZ7qNqoI0wMBcQQyFk6qYojn4OhwG8PHwFKK0CVYPDix/e899pW02Wtk/ql62OOcSWClR@HoW9zJKnIcRFy1GbJ9I1gkWcVgoqklF7aBmO0XqvJRkh2lspNzZCASAPwGUOOc/wyJeaQWVMVOXSUUjBdQo9m1rDRDnavysw6MBrIMcj@xwCoIEeZozmKVqusdtd6zBALcTgTSJ6a8Cdgzx8NuSZ9PVt/0TS4bPX8So3/stTjjRrbz9Z3fnMff6X1yXADv72n/xj@HI7uTd/C2pjD8kdUbwE)

Comment: `f[s ,"foo" ,"" ]` should return an empty string.

Comment: @Arnauld - thanks for pointing that out, edited now!

Comment: Seems OP use (left) index of for end words. Is `rindex` allowed?

Comment: Neither solution gives the empty string for keywords of `wa` and `as`...

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 74 bytes

```javascript
(s,a,b)=>s.substr(p=(s+a).indexOf(a)+a.length,b?s.indexOf(b)-p:1/0).trim()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVU9b8IwEJ3LrziFAbsYEzoWBdQixrZLh35KOIkTXBk7yhkKqvrbqVEJS2EqRAwe7vzk9/zupPchFgKTUhWuY2wq11m0JsgEi2k0QI7zGF1JiohgW1CuTCqXDxkRtC24liZ3UxYPcdePaae47nVDyl2pZoSunUSXCJQIEUwawagJnwIhlQupbSFTEKWdmxSuwjCEeAV3Kikt2syBRxWidGAzUA6B348fQRnllHBqIQO4CAIiZ4VbgdenTE73do7Gd2rpG1DwD8FHFjhq7pd5jmb@aq0MPAf3Ki1//atxo/aO8DT/rIHq5nZUL9OBGZ5idZ@eX2obVR1cWwcPUE36jV0obFOCY6GVI60306I8s@VYJFOilZEQDeCrAaClg1dkIBjEDOS7D5PNNZ8J55HdgF8Og25OfV2QZTRYctQqkaTHOj1K@/6BxBq0WnJtc5JV8RZJBlXhUd/@rH8A)

Quite straightforward...

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 93 bytes

```
sStringTrim@StringTake[s,i=1;If[i*=-1;#=="",0,StringPosition[s,#][[1,i]]]-i&/@#]/._@_:>""&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZLRSsMwFEDf9xUhgT5IurV73OiIFoU9KBP74CyhxDXVi7YpSbohpT/hH/iFfkKNq59g3i7h5HBuSC3sq6yFhYMYq2Q0359fD1ZD85JpqNnfKN5kbigk8Xpb5XCRhPGaJAnGNKITsVMGLKjGUYTneUyBcx5CsGCEL@YFK1YbjIPxvgNp2c7dsHlPyBBuqtzxZOkgU0yq1SZT0@Rk26bt7I3SNecBY6yf9Tgl6CQMKuVRvqtWlkho1TUlWkZRhJ4/0C0ctDKqsshRrdAWqQqBNWh@d50haFyn2/YoMe3dAhgPA/1/6@@pB3NK/BSfvZ6az1pf7@zCvRV7cV9epZ6zH/dP3rr9uIXx8z9OwnmdfBhmw/gD)

Comment: The first solution doesn't give the right answer for keywords of `wa` and `as` and the second solution doesn't load for me at all.

Comment: @Neil Thanks. I hadn't updated the answer for the clarified spec. Somehow the second link had a stray `</b>` in it, but it would have had the same problem anyways.

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 90 bytes

```
func[t s e][p:""if""<> s[append s" "]if e =""[e:[end]]parse t[thru s copy p to[opt" "e]]p]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVA9T8MwEN3zK57cmSpijKASRIwwIAbA8mDis2qpxJZ9aemvD5cUlIDl4X3cezo7kxufyWlT@QajH/pOMwrI6NQoFbxSNzsUbVOi3qEoKBM8CLdKaWq0iMYkmwuBNe/zINkupjMSOOqYWAIkE2Zk@uIGqt3gZAscHekQEznYHAdpvq7rGh9nPIYuxxI9Q6akmBE9Ahdsnx5eEPrAwXI4kvROt/Ixk@320PPOFeRcjF805X5Yu1mcGa@8Ga5zMrA427Vwd9/@94W/vr3/8Rd@skJtUZXRSDn0DI3pN6Cudgqf8eDgL4K8AQZm/AY)

Comment: The result for keywords of `wa` and `as` should be the empty string.

Comment: @Neil Thank you for pointing me this bug - it should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>100</s> 85 bytes

Regex version, still cannot beat the [slicing algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/217448/).

```python
from re import*
r=escape
f=lambda s,b,e:(search(r(b)+'(.+)'+r(e),s)or'  ')[1].strip()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYw/b4NADEd3PoVFBu4KQrTdIjE0KGM7MfSPOhzgUywFfPK5qfLpadJsTejg5f3eczjqjqfHefbCIwgCjYFF7xKpMfYuYOLrvRu7wUEsugLXJqKTfmfEdDbPTJnbLBeDtoiWJQPI7Mf9ZxlVKBg7t3XarODbRRjwgHsOOIAT/poGeKiqCrojPFMvHNkrnKzgRIE9kEYoX7Yt0ERKTumAaZIEoUmNN20BaXo@a6/YufrLm9Ut@0Jv@b9s4f@pWrCvl6dN83/y@va@0FyW@Qc)

Comment: The result for keywords of `wa` and `as` should be the empty string.

Comment: you're right, it's still buggy

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 60 bytes

```
(.*)¶(.+)?¶.*?\1 *(.*?) *(?<!(?=\2).*)(?(2)\2.*|$)|(.|¶)+
$3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZDPCoJAEIfvPsWEBrsqi27XYinpWJc6VHhoyxUWwhXdjMDn8gF8MVsPvcFc5s@P4eNjGmV1JaclOd1jj7CQjoOr4@AmL@DjEKTTP42omHORpxC6TFDXxHpBxCbn1N0QQTjNOQv7gPaE9eNAIy9YTVPmw0e2UKhOvUytCpCNeVcF8CRJ4PGFg342pjWlBXdVy8aCKUHbFthxfwZdaaul1Z2KYw8PNQd4uMyPUWG4dvOO@bvMR3bDBG53Gb7g5XrDNXTAHw) Takes input as start, end, string on separate lines but link is to test suite with header that converts from comma separated string, end, start for convenience. Explanation:

```
(.*)¶
```

Match the start keyword.

```
(.+)?¶
```

Optionally match a non-empty end keyword.

```
.*?\1
```

Find the start keyword as early as possible in the string, plus optional spaces.

```
 *(.*?) *
```

Match as short a result as possible (so that the end keyword is found as early as possible in the string) but also trim spaces around it.

```
(?<!(?=\2).*)
```

Ensure that the end keyword hasn't already been passed at this point.

```
(?(2)\2.*|$)
```

If the end keyword was empty then only match at the end of the string otherwise match the end keyword and the rest of the string.

```
|(.|¶)+
```

If it wasn't possible to match anything, delete everything.

```
$3
```

Keep the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>168</s> <s>152</s> <s>143</s> <s>132</s> 112 bytes

An enormous **-38** thanks to @ceilingcat

```c
#define r strstr(c
*f(c,s,e)int*c,*s,*e;{return*e&&r,s)>r,e)|!r,s)|!r,e)||*e&&(*r,e)=0)?"":r,s)+strlen(s)+!!*s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVLRToMwFH3nK@5KZoDVhS0xJmOb0cVHffJBZTxgKa4JFtKWmWXj2@ctzI1oQ3rPPef2tL2FXX8ydnSFZEWdcZhrk4lyvFke3YznQnJQoI3Cz2NOkHuMasp9IU3AaKBpwKO94qZWMuBXV4pqf6lQPwwstDPig5W8wOJF6N8RMrPiCC0LLj1Eg0Ggo@aIpvCVCun5sHccwME2qQIhq9rECSyArFz4TjVkfMuLsuIZpKqsZQbTMAzhYwdPgqlSl7kBrKpSZaDMQRgN4@fHFzQSRqRGbDmJLvasrHbxJAyTHme4Nsgl8TSJb@zO@z0hlJCGQgusXZes3DPfwovSot4alPv8b3r/sPovvr6999U2haY7YDvlpfJsuwSeLYwwzGFi42hkewencQbYalbtPHtV2rbTj85apdAo98jwVsNQr@XfuJaEAtEGuzlD1LZGJHGYIMtl1ucmllNc10Vbmncb9lZcCv3TCZruobtfCK/iNMcf)

Comment: It's perfectly fine to not build a fully functional program, but it should be at least some callable with defined I/O like a function or a lambda.

In your case something like `char*f(char*s,char*i,char*e){return ...}` would be acceptable

Comment: Here is a [TIO](https://tio.run/##PY5PSwMxFMTPzacYUoREY7t4XfUiHvXkTTzE/GkfrMmSvF2R0s@@pq0ID35vhhkYd7tzbllTcsPkA@4re8qb/eO/1ZxCadcs4fa2XEd1Bpkz6gVBH0rgqSS0dDv1BzJV37RnCElVbYLuj8ucyePLUlL6IFanOuj9Aw@QT2t82wof5jDkMXjYkqfkcdd1HT5/8EKu5Jojo6VGWxg5grhi8/r8BkrEZJnmIHtst02PE@OyXojV2MhRyasqDWJbJk8taaTUuhfH5Rc "C (gcc) – Try It Online") with your code. This is the preferred format here. Note that you're using library functions, thus the `#import<string.h>` statement counts as well, while the boilerplate for a full program does not!

Comment: Thank you very much @movatica! So now if I make a working function I need to count `#include <string.h>` but I can omit to count `#include <stdio.h>` right? and do I need to count the new line between the header and the function as 1 byte?

Comment: My pleasure and welcome to Codegolf! Yes, you got that right and whitespace counts just as well.

Comment: Do you, golfers, have some way to automatically count the characters of your code? Surely I could make a program for that, but I don' know, how do you use to count the characters?

Comment: Click the link to TIO in my second answer :)

Comment: Thank you for everything! I am ready to golf! :)

Comment: @ceilingcat thank you so much! I couldn't find a way to get rid of those `char`. And that `!!` is genial!!

Comment: Omg you are right! Thank you very much :)

Comment: @ceilingcat I am learning a lot of tricks from you! I can't thank you enough

Comment: I tried entering `wa` and `as` and it core dumped. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: If you enter `we` and `as` or whatever, it works properly. So my guess is that in order to shrink the code I introduced some undefined behaviour. But they told me that this is codegolf and even undefined behaviours are allowed as long as the program passes all the tests in at least one compiler. By the way have a look at the number of warnings xD

Comment: @ceilingcat thank you!

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6) <s>95</s> 92 Bytes, No Regex!

```
(i,s,e,t=i.indexOf(s),r=i.lastIndexOf(e))=>t!=-1&r!=-1?(i.substring(t+s.length,r)).trim():''
```

#### How to try it:

Open your browser's JavaScript Console and paste the following.

```
((i,s,e,t=i.indexOf(s),r=i.lastIndexOf(e))=>t!=-1&r!=-1?(i.substring(t+s.length,r)).trim():'')('C# was developed around 2000 by Microsoft as part of its .NET initiative', 'C#', '.NET')
```

Comment: Note that you can add header and footer code in TIO that are ignored in the byte count so you can display the function result, something [like this based on your test code](https://tio.run/##LYzBTsQwDER/xQiJxCIbFY5IZQ@IAwfgwg9kG7cYZeMq9hb4@tJKXJ40b0bzlZakQ@PZDlUyrYNUlUKxyOT96jlooGA9R66Zft5HrxjaFktSe/lXhNg/2lV/uLtpO4@eo15Oao3r5O1WY6E62WdoiHGTZ48Pzq3o3dM1fCeFTAsVmSlDanKpGe67roPTL7zy0ERlNNhWc2oGMgKbQnx7/gCubJyMF3IBtq@de@EQ1z8) or you can check the other Js answers with functions to see how they do it

Comment: Your use of `lastIndexOf` seems to be incorrect; I think it should just be `indexOf`. You should also use `slice` because `substring` does weird things if the second string appears before the first. After that your answer works properly for keywords of `wa` and `as`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 41 bytes

```
≔⎇ζ…θ⌕θζθθ≔⎇η⪫Φ⪪θηκηθθ≔⌕ＡＥθ›ι ¹ε¿ε✂θ⌊ε⊕⌈ε
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU3LasMwELz7K5bkIoNanFxzCqYpLaQEkh9QpXW9VJacleLG@XlVSnvKwjAwOw/dK9Ze2ZS2IdCXEydkp3gWNwntrC22vR/FWcKOnCl8q2sJ5zs21UOml/DuyYkd2YgsjqOlWDJ9tn/Xf/wQLbVba8Ve3VdeGVWJkoQFLMrUKgOznzoQWMOByUVxtKSx@PfkaLgM@SPhzWnGAV1Ek@uu/3q@TUrtEn5UAIMTWj@iAcX@4gysm6aBzzn3aPbBdxGya1QcwXdAMcDzx8sJ8kgkFWnCql1WRUpPk/0F) Link is to verbose version of code. Take care to include sufficient newlines in the input even if one of the keywords is empty. Explanation:

```
≔⎇ζ…θ⌕θζθθ
```

If the end keyword is not empty then truncate the string at its first appearance. (Fortunately `CycleChop` truncates the string to empty if its input is negative.)

```
≔⎇η⪫Φ⪪θηκηθθ
```

If the start keyword is not empty then split the string on the keyword, discard the first element, and join the string again. This results in an empty string if the start keyword does not appear in the string.

```
≔⌕ＡＥθ›ι ¹ε
```

Check whether the string has any non-spaces.

```
¿ε✂θ⌊ε⊕⌈ε
```

If so then print from the first to the last non-space.

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 111 bytes

```r
function(s,a,b,c=?s,`?`=nchar,r=regexpr)trimws(substr(s,`if`((d=r(a,s,f=T))>0,d+?a,c),`if`(?b,r(b,s,f=T)-1,c)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY@xTsQwDIZ3nsLqLYkIqLCHCipGmG4ApjppckSCpLLTKzx9CcctSI2U6f/@z7FpNS4vzkXOFOJBr36ONocUBStURlndsRq6QUf7jqRIkzu4r4lkqX8uLHg2xSzlIfhBiFGTQMXK672Ud60aLztUVv7RzigS5kyvbkou5cq66XewIMPoju4jTW4EpDTHEW7btgXzDU/BUuLkM5TWhJQheQiZ4fr5cQ8hhhwwh6NrLv7dUpZqmvLkZvzrbqF@V3FOoGad8upfRd0A9w99lZ3nvby@1c0KXLAw5ILWHw)

Straightforward approach: finds bounding words using `regexpr` (with argument `f`ixed=`T`rue to ensure that the text string is not interpreted as a regex), gets the `substr`ing between them, and then `trim`s the `w`hite`s`pace from both ends.

Since the functions `nchar` and `regexpr` are each used twice, it's shorter to define single-character aliases.  In the case of `nchar`, we can even redefine the unary operator `?` as its alias, so that we avoid the need for parentheses.  Unfortunately, this trick isn't possible here for `regexpr` because of the need to feed it the additional argument `f`ixed=`T`rue.

Answer (score 0):

### C# 114 bytes

```csharp
(i,s,e)=>{int p=(i+(s??="")).IndexOf(s)+s.Length,q=$"{e}"==""?i.Length:i.IndexOf(e);return p<q?i[p..q].Trim():"";}
```